# Vaadin use function Create field when use addItemAt

Tags: field, vaadin

I have a problem with the Create field vaadin table, nesesito define a field in a table where you can enter text, for that the Create field, each time a new row agrege this field should have focus so I did something like this:

```
public Field createField(Container container, Object itemId,
                Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
            final TextField f=new TextField();      
            f.setVisible(true);

            f.addStyleName("txtronly-textfield");
            if((propertyId=="Cantidad"))
            {

                f.setStyleName("centerTxt");
                f.setReadOnly(true);
                f.setRequired(true);
                f.setMaxLength(9);
                f.focus();
            }
            return f;
}
```

Now when I insert an item use addItemAt (0, item) to be inserted top, but the focusing field is the last in the table. I can not find why this happens if anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Your code within your if-block will never be executed because the if-statement is never true.
Always compare Strings with the equals method.

Try the following:

```
if((propertyId.equals("Cantidad")))
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, if you run the code and if it debuggin, enters, the problem is that it focuses on the last item when I want to do in the first